# v.buffer.distance does not create straight buffers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, buffer

I've re-ran the v.buffer.distance algorithm numerous times in QGIS as well as the GRASS GIS GUI. No matter what setting I pick for straight corners, or caps at the end of polylines, I keep on getting rounded buffers.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Or is there another way in QGIS to get flat ended buffers from lines?

Comment: Do you mean that what is documented in https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/v.buffer.html does not work?

Comment: Yes, the -s in the manual to make straight corners, doesn't work for me. This is regardless of what settings I put for caps at the end of polylines, and regardless of running the tool in GRASS or from the QGIS interface. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.