# v.buffer.distance without cap

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, buffer

In QGIS 2.18.14 Processing Toolbox I started to use `v.buffer.distance` to create fixed-distance buffers around my lines.

I can also make the buffer with square caps (straight ends).

However, I cannot make it **without end cap**. I mean, the option *"Do not make caps at the ends of polylines"* does not seem to work.

This is similar to this recent question [v.buffer.distance does not create straight buffers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262911/v-buffer-distance-does-not-create-straight-buffers-in-qgis), but my situation is different, as I can make square caps (-s) while not being able to cut caps (-c).
(Probably @Annekeds is using QGIS - GRASS plugin, while I am working through Processing Toolbox).

Strangely I can make buffer without caps when I run `v.buffer.column`... so my workaround for now is to use `v.buffer.column` with same distance in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I cannot produce the same issue using both QGIS 2.14.20 and 2.18.14 whether I used v.buffer.distance or v.buffer.column, I got the same result when I Check both "Make Outside Corner Straight" and "Do not make caps at the ends of polylines"

Here is the result using QGIS 2.14.20:

[image]

Here is the result using QGIS 2.18.14

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ahmadhanb! Lightning-fast. Umm...installing 2.14.20 for this does not sound much appealing...

Comment: In fact I have both versions, but i don't rely on 2.18 version as it is still have many issues. I always use the stable LTR release of 2.14.20. Until 2.18.14 becomes stable LTR I will use it.

Comment: I updated my answer. Actually both versions worked fine. What projection are using? I tested on projected UTM data as you can in the images above.

Comment: Really? I am on UTM51N (EPSG 32651).

Comment: Another suggestion is to do `Check geometries` for any possible error.

Comment: Yes, geometry is on my check list, and I have usual samples to test. Thanks again.

Comment: Updated to latest 2.18.16 and the issue is not reproducible anymore. Thanks @ahmadhanb! Always helpful.

Comment: @Kazuhito you are most welcome. I am glad the issue was solved. :)